# Evaluating the limit of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to find the value of   $$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{k+{{n}^{4}}}}}$$

Answer (score 5):

We have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4+n}}\sum_{k=1}^n k \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{\sqrt{k+n^4}}<\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k$$so the limit is $\frac12$ by the squeeze theorem, since $\sum_{k=1}^n k =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by noting that
$$
\frac{k}{\sqrt{k+n^4}}=\frac{k}{n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}},
$$
and that for all $k\leq n$ and $n\geq 1$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^3}}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}}\leq1.
$$
Now, you can simplify
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}.
$$
Can you see how to finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

By the Taylor approximation, $$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk\left(1-\frac k{2n^4}\right)<\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{\sqrt{\frac k{n^4}+1}}<\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk$$ and the width of the squeezing range is $O(\frac1{n^3})$.

So $$\frac12.$$

Comment: you were missing an $n$ in the numerator